# React Native index.js call multiple time on first start

Tags: react-native

When I start debugging. First time index.js call multiple.
[image]

but when I close app from emulator and open again it will work fine.

following is my index.js code.

```
/**
 * @format
 */
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';
 

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingHeadlessTask', () => firebaseBackgroundMessage);
 
function firebaseBackgroundMessage(resp){
     
    try{
        console.log("firebaseBackgroundMessage",resp);
        if(resp.data && resp.data.ActionName){
            console.log("ActionName", resp.data.ActionName);
            global.PushNotification=resp.data;
            
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log("error++++++++++++", error)
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
 
}

 
 
TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService(() => registerPlaybackService);

async function registerPlaybackService() {

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-play', () => TrackPlayer.play());

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-pause', () => TrackPlayer.pause());

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-stop', () => TrackPlayer.destroy());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we should lower the register component syntax to the bottom.

Comment: I had tried but it is not working. issue is still there.

Comment: @vicky AppRegistry.registerComponent is bottom?